# Keras deep learning output format issue

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I'm a newbie in deep learning and Keras. I really hope folks with experience in this field could help me answer the following question.

I downloaded the [cifar10_cnn.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) code from Keras github. I run it with python 3.5.2, Keras 2.0.2 and tried both backends tensorflow 0.12.0-rco and theano 0.9.0. But unfortunately both of them print output something like below:

Epoch 1/200

1/1562 [..............................] - ETA: 92s - loss: 2.2861 - acc: 0.1562

3/1562 [..............................] - ETA: 65s - loss: 2.3133 - acc: 0.1354

5/1562 [..............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 2.3202 - acc: 0.1125

7/1562 [..............................] - ETA: 57s - loss: 2.3168 - acc: 0.1071

what I expect is some like below:

Epoch 1/200

32/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 3138s - loss: 2.3238 - acc: 0.0625

64/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 1579s - loss: 2.3165 - acc: 0.0625

96/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 1059s - loss: 2.3091 - acc: 0.0625

128/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 798s - loss: 2.3070 - acc: 0.0781

160/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 643s - loss: 2.3056 - acc: 0.0750

you could observe that 50000/32 = 1562.5, but I don't know why the output was changed like that. It's very confusing for new comer to see the numerator is 1 and denominator is 1562. Is this change related to python3?

Another confusion for me is where the output comes from? which API leads to the above output?

Comment: When you use fit_generator, the progress bar uses steps instead of samples, this makes more sense as the generator outputs batches. This change was in Keras 2.0.0 and has nothing to do with Python3 or any other API.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't understand why this output is more appropriate. I didn't see any progress bar and I just saved the above output from terminal into a log file. In my opinion, it's more straightforward to use batch size over the number of training samples. Yes, I agree that it's not related to python3. Thank you

Comment: it is more appropriate because the steps match 1:1 to calls to the generator, while using samples is less direct.

Comment: OK. I think you are right. Occasionally I saw the keras author's reply in another post. I cited his original comment as follows.         You should all note that generator methods have switched from being
sample-based (one epoch = defined number of samples) to being step-based
(one epoch = defined number of batches). The conversion is handled
automatically when possible, but if you are using custom generators then
that may not be possible.

For more info, see the release notes:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/wiki/Keras-2.0-release-notes

Comment: Just a little confusing if it's an indivisible case